# Why do I get a 'Failed to read artifact descriptor' exception when I depend on `com.datomic/ion`?

Tags: amazon-web-services, clojure, cloud, datomic

I have a Datomic Cloud / Ions project that I can't get working on a different computer. Just typing `clj` in the hopes of getting to a REPL fails with the following exception (caused-by chain included; stack traces elided; formatted for clarity):

- `Error building classpath. Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.datomic:ion:jar:0.9.34`
- `org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.datomic:ion:jar:0.9.34`
- `Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact com.datomic:ion:pom:0.9.34 from/to datomic-cloud (s3://datomic-releases-1fc2183a/maven/releases): Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain`
- `Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact com.datomic:ion:pom:0.9.34 from/to datomic-cloud (s3://datomic-releases-1fc2183a/maven/releases): Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain`
- `Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain`

If I comment out the `com.datomic/ion` dependency in the `deps.edn` file, the dependencies download, and I can get to a REPL successfully.

Why does fetching dependencies fail when including the Ion dependency?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that something somewhere in the Ions code uses the AWS SDK to fetch Maven dependencies from S3 Maven repositories. This requires that the user have the "read publicly available S3 buckets" permission. So ensure that:

1. you have an account on AWS,
2. your credentials are available locally (see the `aws configure` command), and
3. that your AWS user hasn't for some odd reason missed out on that permission (which should be included by default).